# Redirect doesn't work laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, model, controller

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/',['uses'=>'Admin\IndexController@index','as'=>'adminIndex']);
    Route::resource('/cat-n-cat','Admin\CatalogsNCategoriesController');
});
```

controller:

```
public function update($data)
    {
            $category = Category::find($data[0]['id']);
            $result = $this->category_rep->updateCategory($data,$category);    
            if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['error'])) {    
                return back()->with($result);
            }    
             redirect('admin')->with($result);    
    }
```

Model:

```
public function updateCategory($data,$category){
        $data=$data[0];
        if (empty($data)) {
            return array('error' => 'No data');
        }
        $result = $this->one($data['name']);            
        if (isset($result->id) && ($result->id != $category->id)) {
            return ['error' => 'Category with this name already exists'];
        }    
        $category->fill($data);    
        if($category->update()){    
            return ['status' => 'Category has been added'];
        }
    }
```

After editing category redirect doesn't trigger and i stay in same page. How to fix it and what is the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: have you tried like this              return redirect('admin')->with($result);

Comment: still doesn't work :c

Comment: what error you are facing

Comment: any error there?

Comment: @rahul_m no error, just still staying in same page, no redirect

Comment: @Vladd no error, just still staying in same page, no redirect

Comment: if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['error'])) {    
dd($result);
                return back()->with($result);
            }    

what it returns?

Comment: is this one that is not working? redirect('admin')->with($result);
Maybe you never get to it and in your if above, you are redirected back()?

Comment: can you tell us steps of how and when its not working

Comment: @Vladd

array:1 [▼
  "error" => "Category with this name already exists"
]

Comment: @Vladd its when im trying to add category with name, that already exists, if not, this if block ofc doesn't trigger

Comment: Could you please check route using artisan command  php artisan route:list  is any route available that belongs to admin?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException]
thats what I get when typing php artisan route:list

Comment: share your all routes ?

Comment: So, when you add category with name which does not exists, your redirect('admin')->with($result); does not work?

Comment: try to redirext to route: return redirect()->route('admin')

Comment: What happens when you `dd($result)` before the redirects?

Comment: or this:
return redirect('admin')->with('result', $result);

Comment: @Niklesh

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/',['uses'=>'Admin\IndexController@index','as'=>'adminIndex']);
    Route::resource('/products','Admin\ProductController');
    Route::resource('/permissions','Admin\PermissionsController');
    Route::resource('/cat-n-cat','Admin\CatalogsNCategoriesController');
});

Comment: Issue is about route defining, it's not like redirection issue so could you please confirm if you have all routes are defined correct or not?

Comment: @Vladd So, when you add category with name which does not exists, your redirect('admin')->with($result); does not work?

it doesn't even redirect when error exists

Answer (score 2):

return redirect,

```
return redirect('/admin')->with(compact('result'));
```

Here is the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects).

It should work.

Comment: still don't redirects me

Answer (score 2):

Use At Top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

and

```
public function update($data)
{
        $category = Category::find($data[0]['id']);
        $result = $this->category_rep->updateCategory($data,$category);    
        if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['error'])) {    
            return Redirect('<PreviousControllerName>')->with($result); //Change It
        }    
         return Redirect('/')->with($result);    //Change It
}
```

Comment: Have you used 'Admin' as namespace,  In your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You should return it:

```
return redirect('admin')->with($result);
```

Comment: No, I'm not getting error, just don't getting redirected to site.loc/admin

Answer (score 0):

`with` has two parameters

```
 return redirect('/admin/')->with('result',$result);
```

Comment: @Batmannn : did you also try with `adminIndex`  or `/admin/adminIndex` ?

Comment: Tried both, still no result :c

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check with defining all your Routes in below format and then try redirecting in appropriate route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin','middleware'=>'auth'), function() {
    Route::post('student/cust_post', ['as' => 'admin.index', 'uses' => 'Admin\IndexController@index']
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
return redirect()->route('adminIndex');
```